# How to deep compare each element with other elements in a list in scala (optional fileds)

Tags: scala

I have case class that represents report, and report have expenses.

```
case class FakeExpense(amount: Option[Double], country: Option[String], currency: Option[String])
case class FakeReport(id: Int, expenses: List[FakeExpense])
```

and I want to return true/false if report is valid or not, and it is not valid if there is 2 expenses with the exact same fields...what would be the right way with scala to do something like this?

a valid report:

```
val report = FakeReport(1, List(FakeExpense(Some(150), Some("US"), Some("USD")),FakeExpense(Some(85), Some("DE"), Some("EUR"))))
```

a non valid report:

```
val report = FakeReport(2, List(FakeExpense(Some(150), Some("US"), Some("USD")),FakeExpense(Some(150), Some("US"), Some("USD"))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [`List.distinct`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinct:C) approach like so

```
def isValidReport(report: FakeReport): Boolean =
  report.expenses.distinct.length == report.expenses.length
```

The above solution makes three passes through the list. Applying Luis' comment we can reduce to two passes like so

```
def isValidReport(report: FakeReport): Boolean = {
  report.expenses.sizeIs == report.expenses.iterator.distinct.length
}
```

We shave off one pass because `distinct.length` collapses to a single transformation in `iterator.distinct.length`. [`sizeIs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066252/5205022) is a potential quick-savings where we might not have to go through the whole list.

Here is a single-pass tail-recursive solution based on `HashSet` having [O(eC)](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/performance-characteristics.html) lookup and insertion

```
def isValidReport(report: FakeReport): Boolean = {
  val set = mutable.HashSet[FakeExpense]()
  @tailrec def loop(l: List[FakeExpense]): Boolean = l match {
    case Nil => true
    case h :: t => if (set.add(h)) loop(t) else false
  }
  loop(report.expenses)
}
```

Also note how we might return early on first duplicate.

Comment: I would use an `iterator` on the first one and `sizeIs` to reduce the number of iterations.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I could not figure out how `iterator` helps however I have updated question with single-pass solution based on `HashSet`.

Comment: the `iterator` before the `distinct` would reduce the number of iterations from two to one.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah, do you mean because `iterator.distinct.length` becomes single transformation?

Comment: Yeah, anyways your `HashSet` solution is better :p

Answer (score 3):

If you need *exactly* same reports disregarding double comparison with epsilon(|a-b| < epsilon, where epsilon is small enough), you just can turn list to set as it will remove duplicate entries and then check if the size of your list changed.

```scala
fakeReport.expenses.toSet.length == fakeReport.expenses.length
```

It will work till everything that inside your classes you want to use with == correctly implement equals methods (primitive types, most of default classes, case classes and objects do so). What will not implement this correctly is an array and possibly certain java classes and these classes wrapped into AnyVal classes.