# hasDefiniteSize and knownSize

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am going through the `List` methods in Scala.

```
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 10)
```

I am quite confused by `hasDefiniteSize` and `knownSize`.

For `List`, `hasDefiniteSize` returns `true` and `knownSize` returns `-1`.

What is the exact theory behind these methods?

Comment: For what kind of list? Could you provide the example?

Comment: val mylist = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 10)

Answer (score 6):

This method is defined by a superclass of `List` which is common with possibly endless collections (like `Stream`s, `LazyList`s and `Iterator`s).

For more details, I believe the documentation puts it best.

Here is the one for [`hasDefiniteSize` in version 2.13.1](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#hasDefiniteSize:Boolean):

> Tests whether this collection is known to have a finite size. All
> strict collections are known to have finite size. For a non-strict
> collection such as Stream, the predicate returns true if all elements
> have been computed. It returns false if the stream is not yet
> evaluated to the end. Non-empty Iterators usually return false even if
> they were created from a collection with a known finite size.
>
> Note: many collection methods will not work on collections of infinite
> sizes. The typical failure mode is an infinite loop. These methods
> always attempt a traversal without checking first that hasDefiniteSize
> returns true. However, checking hasDefiniteSize can provide an
> assurance that size is well-defined and non-termination is not a
> concern.

Note that `hasDefiniteSize` is deprecated with the following message:

> (Since version 2.13.0) Check .knownSize instead of .hasDefiniteSize
> for more actionable information (see scaladoc for details)

The [documentation for `knownSize`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#knownSize:Int) further states:

> The number of elements in this collection, if it can be cheaply
> computed, -1 otherwise. Cheaply usually means: Not requiring a
> collection traversal.

`List` is an implementation of a linked list, which is why `List(1, 2, 3).hasDefiniteSize` returns `true` (the collection is not boundless) but `List(1, 2, 3).knownSize` returns `-1` (computing the collection size requires traversing the whole list).

Answer (score 3):

Some collections know their size

```
Vector(1,2,3).knownSize   // 3
```

and some do not

```
List(1,2,3).knownSize     // -1
```

If a collection knows its size then some operations can be optimised, for example, consider how [`Iterable#sizeCompare`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/f7ab2748e66c3d67cd21e353471c8377f880e739/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L316) uses `knownSize` to possibly return early

```
  def sizeCompare(that: Iterable[_]): Int = {
    val thatKnownSize = that.knownSize

    if (thatKnownSize >= 0) this sizeCompare thatKnownSize
    else {
      val thisKnownSize = this.knownSize

      if (thisKnownSize >= 0) {
        val res = that sizeCompare thisKnownSize
        // can't just invert the result, because `-Int.MinValue == Int.MinValue`
        if (res == Int.MinValue) 1 else -res
      } else {
        val thisIt = this.iterator
        val thatIt = that.iterator
        while (thisIt.hasNext && thatIt.hasNext) {
          thisIt.next()
          thatIt.next()
        }
        java.lang.Boolean.compare(thisIt.hasNext, thatIt.hasNext)
      }
    }
  }
```

See related question [Difference between size and sizeIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066006/difference-between-size-and-sizeis)